# How to run a shell command in Linux startup RC file

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to run a shell command in the Linux rc startup script. But the command execution is not successful. I cannot creats a shell script file for this command. Please help on how to execute a shell command in rc file. The command I am giving is as below,

```
sh -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts"
```

Thanks for your help

Phani

Comment: @RahulRDhobi, I do not see any logs as this is a startup script

Comment: can you provide your rc script?